# About js objects

Tags: javascript

my English is not so good, but i try to explain my self clear.
I just started learn JS objects and stumbled upon the problem that i can't understand.

I got a simple object like

```
var cars = {
   doors: 4,
   wheels: 4
}
```

and when i trying to create an object like this:

```
   var Opel = new car()
```

I got an error `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

And when i do it like this :

```
Opel = Object.create(cars)
```

all going fine.

And when i writing a an Object like this :

```
 function cars() {}
```

a method to declare the object with new, work correctly.
I can't understand what the difference between thous two type of writing the objects.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Please keep reading the tutorials on JS, it will come to you. Meanwhile, SO is not really designed to be a replacement for learning a language on your own.

Comment: I recommend to read the MDN JavaScript Guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects , which explains all the different ways of creating an object.

Comment: I'm understand, that when i write it like a function it is constructor.it is different from PHP, but why without it  gives an error when i declaring it with new? because it's don't have constructor?

Comment: Maybe the following answer can help. It answers what a constructor function does and what prototype does: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Comment: You can only call **functions** with `new`. As the error tells you, `car` is not a function, hence you can't call it with `new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't understand prototyping correct.

To define a class you create a simple function, like:

```
function Car(){
   this.doors = 4; //For instance, not really necessary 
}
```

You can set properties on `this` in the function.

Then you define a prototype, every object of class "Car" will have all this properties (and "methods"):

```
Car.prototype = {
   doors: 4, //we don't need to set this again if we already did in the constructor, but I'll leave if it anyway
   wheels: 4
}
```

Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript for more.

Comment: thanks. one more question. when i creating a object like var foo = {}  what this means? i came from PHP and in js it is different as i see

Comment: @Viktorino You create an empty object, like `new stdClass()` in PHP or an empty associative array. In JavaScript there are no instances of a class, only objects which were created from a prototype and therefore have the object's functions (methods) and properties (instance variables)

Comment: @Viktorino `foo={doors:4}` is an instance of an object (object literal) Not sure what the equivalent in PHP is but I think it would be an array `array('doors'=>4)` If you need to create many instances with roughly the same characteristics you use a constructor function in JavaScript or a class in PHP.

Comment: aaaa.. now i understand it. thank you for help!